# Use Glide to Show Large Vector Drawable on Lollipop and above Devices

Tags: android, android-studio, android-glide, android-vectordrawable

I'm able to use BumpTech `Glide` to show a large Vector Drawable on pre-lollipop devices but unable to do so on lollipop and above...The activity starts but the `Imageview` is not shown.

Here is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF5722"
    tools:context=".Main.SplashScreen2.SplashScreen2">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSplashScreen2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_of_ahilya_ghat_river_bank_of_varanasi" />

</FrameLayout>
```

here is the java file

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.raviseth.searchviewtrials.Main.MainActivityListViewPage.activities.MainActivity;
import com.example.raviseth.searchviewtrials.R;

import uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoViewAttacher;

public class SplashScreen2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    FloatingActionButton fabSplashScreen2;
    ImageView imageViewSpashScreen2;
    PhotoViewAttacher photoViewAttacher = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashsreen2);

        imageViewSpashScreen2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewSplashScreen2);
        if (imageViewSpashScreen2 != null) {
            photoViewAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageViewSpashScreen2);
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                    .load(R.drawable.ghat)
                    .into(imageViewSpashScreen2);
            photoViewAttacher.update();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue? any logcat? kindly post a complete question

Comment: well this is a complete question.... on lolipo and above the activity with that imageview starts but the image is not shown.....and on pre-lolipop devices image can be seen

Comment: @Anders there is no error msg... its just that the image wont show up

Comment: what does your `VectorDrawable` look like?

Comment: @pskink it does not show up on lolipop and above...its like the imageview becomes invisible

Comment: post your code then

Comment: and where is `VectorDrawable` stuff here?